# One/Two tailed testing of a single random variable in case of unknown mean and known variance

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

Suppose we have a random variable $Y$ which follows normal distribution of unknown mean $\mu$ and variance is $9$. Suppose we have to calculate the one or two tailed confidence interval, will the formula be the same i.e. 
  $ P( -z_{\alpha/2} \le \frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma} \le z_{\alpha/2})$

Comment: No your interval only represents a two-sided test.

Comment: @MichaelChernick So, what should I do in this case?